# How to install Megasync on Ubuntu 22.04 arm64?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, arm64, mega

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a ARM64 computer.

I want to use [MegaSync](https://mega.nz/desktop) desktop client.

However the MegaSync client is only available for Ubuntu (amd64) and Raspbian (armhf).

Its source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAsync/), so it may be possible to use it in arm64.

I tried adding the `armhf` architecture in dpkg, but the armhf .deb file (for Raspbian Buster) cannot be installed in Ubuntu 22.04 due to missing dependencies.

Comment: Which ARM64 CPU are you using? They don't all support the full 32-bit instruction set found in the Hard Float variant 

Comment: @matigo It is a Oracle cloud server with Ampere A1 processor (also updated the question with this information). They provide 4 cores with 24 GB RAM (can be accessed over SSH/XRDP) as a free service :)

Comment: Hmm ... I cannot find any non-marketing technical details about those processors, so do not know whether they can handle armhf code (even if the dependencies are met) 

Comment: @matigo With some trial and error, I found which all dependencies have to be manually installed, and which all can be pulled in with apt. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the armhf architecture.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

Now, update the software repositories.

```
sudo apt update
```

Download the megasync desktop client (armhf) for Raspbian Buster.

```
wget https://mega.nz/linux/repo/Raspbian_10.0/armhf/megasync-Raspbian_10.0_armhf.deb
```

First, download the missing dependencies from focal repositories.

```
wget https://mirror.nishi.network/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_armhf.deb
wget https://mirror.nishi.network/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libr/libraw/libraw19_0.19.5-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb
```

Install these missing dependencies with `apt`.

```
sudo apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_armhf.deb
sudo apt install ./libraw19_0.19.5-1ubuntu1_armhf.deb
```

Finally, install MegaSync.

```
sudo apt install ./megasync-Raspbian_10.0_armhf.deb
```

---

You will have to activate either of the `Ubuntu Appindicators` or `Appindicator and KStatusNotifierItem Support` extensions so that the Mega tray icon works properly in GNOME.

---

### End Results

[image]
MegaSync armhf version working on an arm64 computer.